# text shows appears through fixed div

Tags: html, css

I made a fixed div that stays at the top of the page. but when you scroll text shows up through the div. You can have a look at it [here](http://www.bindmind.net/dev/). Just scroll down to where the forum categories are.

The css for the whole div is located [here](http://bindmind.net/dev/ajax/topbar.css)

Comment: Funny thing, I'm actually trying to implement your problem as a feature. Unfortunately your first link is broken. If you still know what your site looked like, could you explain it a little so I can reproduce the effect? It's hard to tell from just the css what was going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the css-property z-index to the toolbar. Something like this:

```
z-index: 999;
```

This will make sure your toolbar is always on top.

Comment: Thanks. Worked, but I changed it to 9001... :)